# Changing fqdn in centos without prompting password from sudo user

Tags: linux, centos, fqdn, unattended-processing

For root user we can change FQDN as host-name like this:

```
hostname 'test.com'
```

But now, I need to change host-name from other users also we can use like this;

```
sudo  hostname 'test.com'
```

But, it prompting for password, other users also have password, how to give that password without manual interruption.

Thanks,
Indu

Answer (score 0):

passwordless sudo.

setup sudo to allow hostname to be usable without password to those users who need it.

add a ine like this to /etc/sudoers

```
@hostchangers ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/hostname
```

and add those who need that priveledge to group hostchangers (you'll have to dcreate that group) then they'll have to log in again

Comment: when giving passwordless sudo  it shows like this -bash: passwordless: command not found

Comment: the command is just `sudo hostname example.org` if you have the right permissions in sudoers it will not ask you for your password. see edits too.

Comment: for changing in /etc/sudoers file also it prompts for password.Can we give password  in sudo command itself without prompting.

Comment: thanks Jasen,but there is no possible without we edit?,why iam asking this when opening sudoers file of etc also it prompts password.

Comment: it's tecnically possible you's have to open a pseudo-tty and run sudo  in it and then send the password, last time i looked it was more trouble than it was worth.